# Execute code when textboxes have data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, textbox

I have a project which I have to calculate the coordenates between two points. The first coordenates are calculated once the user enters in three text boxes the street, province and city.

How can I execute the code I have in PHP once the user fills out all three boxes and not before?

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia">
    <input type="text" name="municipio" id="municipio">
    <input type="text" name="calle" id="calle">
    <input type="submit" value="&#161;Buscar!"/>
</form>
```

This is the form the user has to fill in. Once the user writes in all three (without mattering the order) I have php code which Im not sure if it can execute once these boxes have values.

What should I have to use to accomplish this? Ajax? Jquery? Javascript?

Not really sure,

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you looking for this?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var flag = false;
        $("input[type=text]").change(function () {
            flag = true;
            $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val().trim() == "") {
                    flag = false;
                }
            });
            if (flag) {
                alert("all have values");
                $("input[type=submit]").trigger("click");
            }
          alert(values);
        });


    });
```

**edit**

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" class="tobeChecked" name="provincia" id="provincia">
<input type="text" class="tobeChecked" name="municipio" id="municipio">
<input type="text" class="tobeChecked" name="calle" id="calle">
<input type="submit" value="&#161;Buscar!"/>
</form>

$(document).ready(function () {
        var flag = false;
        $(".tobeChecked").change(function () {
            var values = "";
            flag = true;
            $(".tobeChecked").each(function () {
                values += $(this).val().trim() + "+";
                if ($(this).val().trim() == "") {
                    flag = false;
                }
            });
            if (flag) {
                alert("all have values");
                $("input[type=submit]").trigger("click");
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: This is a good way but I have more texboxes in the same form (I didnt add them since they are irrelevant to my case). Could I control the textboxes with a counter maybe? When once box is filled sum + 1 and if it another is emptied subtract 1. So when the sum = 3 (each box with text) than the code executes until than nothing occurs.

Comment: @MONZTAAA : this code will check all the text boxes in your code.

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned I have more textboxes which dont need to be checked. Only the three that I have put are the ones that need to be validated (I didnt add the others since they werent important, sorry for not explaining that).

Comment: @MONZTAAA then you can give class name for the textboxes you want to be checked. Then replace the code like $(".classname").each(function () {

Comment: Thanks Anoop Joshi, its working good now! I just have one more doubt. I need to get these three values and replace the spaces for "+". For example: Tonight is the night (textbox1) to replace (textbox2) these texts (textbox3) - Result should be: Tonight+is+the+night,to+replace,these+texts

Answer (score 0):

Create a function to validate the required field for those three text boxes and once all are filled with values execute your script:

```
$('#provincia,#municipio,#calle').blur(function(){

            if($('#provincia').val() !="" && $('#municipio').val() !="" && $('#calle').val() !=""){
               // Do your process here
            }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery validate plugin to validate these 3 input fields on the client side itself, In that way, the user cannot submit the form until he completely fills the input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Give your Button an ID like:

```
 <input type="submit" id="button" value="&#161;Buscar!"/>
```

Then you can do this in JQuery:

```
$("#button").click(function(){

    //Get the value of the fields
    var textfield1 = document.getElementById("provincia").value;
    var textfield2 = document.getElementById("municipio").value;
    var textfield3 = document.getElementById("calle").value;

    //Check if Values are filled
    if ( !textfield1.match(/\S/) || !textfield2.match(/\S/) || !textfield3.match(/\S/))
        {
           //execute your script

        }
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery **.change()** function

```
$( "#provincia" ).change(function() {

   //you  can do something here

   alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```